# Ubuntu 11.10 graphics errors?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, gui, intel

[image: Screenshot!]

See the problem here?  The GUI for the file browser looks strange like this.  I have an EVGA GeForce GTX560Ti graphics card.  I got the drivers Ubuntu asked me to get.  However this still happens from time to time.  Restarting fixes about 75% of the time.  Also, from the login screen, the power menu (with suspend, shut down, restart) also looks like this.

How can I fix this?  It's really annoying.

PS:  My processor is an Intel i5, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That very same thing happened to my Ubuntu 11.10  after I had installed BleachBit and ran it..!! I did wonder if it was a coincidence.
I reinstalled the Light Themes package and it sorted itself out after a log out and back in. Again.. Coincidence..??
Alls well now though.

Comment: I do not have BleachBit.  I'll try reinstalling the themes.

Answer (score 0):

It can possibly be an issue with gnome-settings-daemon. If that's the case, then I think switching to another theme and back would do the trick. Remember to install updates.

Comment: I've already tried both.